# Sentinel 3 SLSTR data via Sentinelsat?

Tags: python, sentinel, sentinelsat

Im trying to query for Sentinel 3 SLSTR products using Sentinelsat as follow:

```
products = api.query(footprint,
                     date=('20200101', '20201201'),
                     platformname='Sentinel-3',
                     instrumentshortname='SLSTR',
                     cloudcoverpercentage=(0, 100))
```

No products are returned.

When I remove the instrumentshortname argument, only Synergy and OLCI products are returned. Is there a way to retrieve the SLSTR products from Sentinel 3 using Sentinelsat?